# SQLite preparedStatement : question mark not recognised

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I'm having an error trying to generate a preparedStatement based on a query.

Here is the query:

```
private static final String SQL_SUPPRIMER_TOUS_SAUF_PLUS_RECENT = 
" delete from vue4 where nomdomaine=\'?\' and dateeditionvue4 in" +
" ( ( select dateeditionvue4 from VUE4 where nomdomaine = \"\" and >dateeditionVue4 < (?) and dateeditionVue4 > (?) ) " +
" < ( select max(dateEditionVue4) from VUE4 where nomdomaine = >\"\" and dateeditionVue4 < (?) and dateeditionVue4 > (?) ) ) ";
```

Here is the preparedStatement:

```
        // Préparation de la requête SQL
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_SUPPRIMER_TOUS_SAUF_PLUS_RECENT);
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);

        for (String domaine : listeCodeDomaine){
            for (MoisBudgetaire mois : listeDeMois ){

                preparedStatement.setObject(1, domaine );
                preparedStatement.setObject(2, domaine );
                preparedStatement.setObject(3, mois.getDateFin());
                preparedStatement.setObject(4, mois.getDateDebut() );
                preparedStatement.setObject(5, domaine );
                preparedStatement.setObject(6, mois.getDateFin());
                preparedStatement.setObject(7, mois.getDateDebut() );

                // Ajout de la requête au batch
                preparedStatement.addBatch();

            }           }
```

I'm getting this Exception:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
at org.sqlite.core.CorePreparedStatement.batch(CorePreparedStatement.java:128)  
at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3PreparedStatement.setObject(JDBC3PreparedStatement.java:388)   
at dao.Vue4DAO.supprimerAnciensEnregistrements(Vue4DAO.java:95)     
at extracteurs.ExtracteurVue4.extraireToutesLesDonnees(ExtracteurVue4.java:107)     
at app.PTFL.main(PTFL.java:41)
```

It seems like the question marks between the quotation marks are not recognized.

Comment: Then your query is still wrong and you're escaping things that shouldn't be escaped. I'm not sure if you understood, but the correct for would be `where nomdomaine=?` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to escape `'` when it's inside a String literal's `"` quotations.

You also can't write `'?'` even if the column is a text type, it's still just `?`.